# I am getting absolutely bonkers syntax errors in my program

Tags: python, syntax

I'm getting crazy syntax errors in my terminal. For example:

```
end_result = ASCII_to_alpha_list(coded_list)
return ''.join(end_result)
```

Returns

```
End_result = ASCII_to_alpha_list(coded_list)
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

What's weirding me out especially is that it doesn't matter what I put down - it returns the same error.

```
print 'Hi'
```

returns

```
print "Hi"
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Beginner coder here. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What does this have to do with iOS?

Comment: Python 2.7 or 3? The print one looks like a Python 3 error :)

Comment: For your `print` error, are you using Python 2, or Python 3? Why does the first error contain `End_result` when the code example shows `end_result`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost certainly have an error on the line before, probably a missing close parenthesis.